# null or undefined for ternary operator styling in React

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am wondering if theres a specific condition isnt fulfilled when styling a component, should we be using null, or undefined, or something else.

Example:

```
        errorStyle: {
            right: locale === Locales.ARABIC ? 0 : null,
            left: locale !== Locales.ARABIC ? 0 : null,
            ...
        },
```

or

```
        errorStyle: {
            right: locale === Locales.ARABIC ? 0 : undefined,
            left: locale !== Locales.ARABIC ? 0 : undefined,
            ...
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) can do the trick which is used to reset a property to its inherited value if the property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. So your style will be like this:

```css
errorStyle: {
    right: locale === Locales.ARABIC ? 0: 'unset',
    left: locale !== Locales.ARABIC ? 0: 'unset',
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`initial`, `inherit`, `unset` are all accepted values as `default`

Ex:

`right: locale === Locales.ARABIC ? 0 : 'initial',`

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right#Syntax)